# Is there a reason my compiler aligns chars to 4 bytes in debug and 8 bytes in release mode?

Tags: c++, char, alignment

In debug mode whenever I create chars like this it's 4-byte aligned in debug mode, and in release mode it's always 8-byte aligned. This happens whether I run it in 32 bit build mode or 64 bit. I am using Visual Studio 2017. But I have tried it at Ideone.com online compiler, and it always passes this test:

```
char charbuff[] = "h";
if ((unsigned long long)&charbuff[0] % 8ULL != 0) throw;
```

I know that string literals have an extra byte, I tried "hh" and the only difference is that in 32-bit build mode sometimes it fails (the 8-byte alignment).

Are new variables never allocated to memory that isn't at least 4-byte aligned? Is this a feature of the language or the operating system allocator?

Edit: I am placing it on the stack in the main function:

```
int main()
{
    char charbuff[] = "hh";
    char charbuff2[] = "hh";
    char charbuff3[] = "hh";

    if ((unsigned long long)&charbuff[0] % 8ULL != 0) throw;
    if ((unsigned long long)&charbuff2[0] % 8ULL != 0) throw;
    if ((unsigned long long)&charbuff3[0] % 8ULL != 0) throw;
}
```

This always passes in release mode. In debug mode it'll always pass a 4-byte aligned. On Ideone.com it always passes this.

Comment: Where is `charbuff` located, on the stack or globally?  If you add a `char charbuff2[] = "i";` immediately after `charbuff`, what alignment do you get?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes I've tried adding "hh" and "i", different combos, always passes in my release mode, and in debug always passes a 4-byte test. On Ideon.com also, always passes 8-byte aligned.

Comment: With a debug build, is the difference between the addresses of `charbuff` and `charbuff2` 4 or 8 bytes?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Mine goes with memory addresses ending in fb54, fb74, fb94. That's 32 bytes apart right?

Comment: Yeah, that's 32 bytes.  That's a lot more than I can explain.  Maybe there's padding, or sentinel values to check for out-of-bounds writes?

Comment: Is there a difference in optimization flags between debug and release modes?

Some platforms executes faster if data are aligned properly and compiler, when optimizing for speed, aligns data accordingly to the platform

Comment: @hutorny Yes, definitely, in release mode lots of optimisations are on. I'm learning about pointer alignment and I'm just wondering in this case if there's a necessity for stuff to be aligned to four bytes or 8 bytes. Creating single chars seems strange that they would be aligned to 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: The compiler is not aligning chars to 8 bytes in your example. It is aligning char arrays.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Happens also with chars, debug 4-byte aligned, release 8-byte aligned. Tried heap allocation too.  Ran into another curious thing, my compiler let's me write char char1 = 'abcd'; but not char char1 = 'abcde'; says "Too many characters in character constant. I never knew you could put more than one character in single quotes. Edit: I just stumbled upon multicharacter literals.